Reductive but not linearly reductive groups
I am beginning to learn reductive groups. I stumble upon this blog post where the author moivates reductive groups by introducing linearly reductive groups, namely, those with semi-simple representation category.
There is a theorem stating that these two notions are equivalent in characteristic zero. In positive characteristic, I found somewhere that special linear groups $SL_n$ are not linearly reductive. However, there is no proof there. Can someone provide me a proof or a reference for counterexamples (reductive but not linearly reductive)?

Just to clarify, it's not just some weird property of $SL_n$. In characteristic $p$, the only connected linearly reductive groups are tori. This is extremely restrictive. (If the group is not connected, then its connected component must be a torus, and its index in the group must not be divisible by $p$.)

Let me clarify the answer of Sasha, with some more concrete computations. For simplicity, let's take $p=2$. We consider $k^2$ with standard basis $e_1,e_2$. The second symmetric power $V=\operatorname{Sym}^2(k^2)$ with the induced basis
$$\left \{e_1 \otimes e_1 , e_1 \otimes e_2 = e_2 \otimes e_1, e_2 \otimes e_2 \right \}.$$
We let $SL_2$ acts on $V$ by the rule $g \cdot (v_1 \otimes v_2) = gv_1 \otimes gv_2$ in which the second multiplication is multiplication of matrices. Using characteristic $2$, we can compute that if we write
$$g =  \begin{pmatrix}
 a & b \\
c  & d \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
then $ge_1 = ae_1 + ce_2$ and $ge_2 = be_1 + de_2$, and hence
\begin{align*}
g \cdot (e_1 \otimes e_1) & = a^2 (e_1 \otimes e_1) + c^2(e_2 \otimes e_2) \\ 
g \cdot (e_2 \otimes e_2) & = b^2 (e_1 \otimes e_1) + d^2(e_2 \otimes e_2) \\ 
g \cdot (e_1 \otimes e_2) & = ab( e_1 \otimes e_1) + cd(e_2\otimes e_2) + e_1 \otimes e_2
\end{align*}
(the last identity we have used determinant $1$). In general,
$$g \cdot (x (e_1 \otimes e_1) + y(e_2 \otimes e_2) + z (e_1\otimes e_2))$$
is equal
$$(xa^2+yb^2+zab)(e_1 \otimes e_1) + (xc^2+yd^2+zcd)(e_2 \otimes e_2) + z(e_1 \otimes e_2).$$
If we denote $W$ to be the subspace of $V$ generated by $e_1 \otimes e_1, e_2 \otimes e_2$ then $W$ is $\mathrm{SL}_2$-invariant. The quotient map
$$V \longrightarrow V/W = \left< e_1 \otimes e_2 \right>$$
is not surjective after applying the fixed point functors, i.e.,
$$V^G \longrightarrow (V/W)^G$$
is not surjective since there is nothing mapped to $e_1\otimes e_2$. Indeed, if it is the case, then such a element is necessarily of the form (by invariance and surjectivity assumption) as above
with $(x-1)a^2+yb^2+ab = xc^2+(y-1)d^2+cd=0$ for any $a,b,c,d$ such that $ad-bc=1$, which cannot be true.

If $V$ is the standard representation of $\mathrm{SL}_n$ over a field of characteristic $p$, the natural projection
$$
V^{\otimes p} \to \mathrm{Sym}^p(V)
$$
is surjective, but not split.

What is the standard representation?

Irreducible $n$-dimensional, so that $\mathrm{SL}_n = \mathrm{SL}(V)$.

What is the role of characteristic p in the non-splitting here? I don't find it obvious.

@AlexeyDo the splitting, which works in characteristic $0$ or characteristic $p$ for $p > n$, requires you to divide by $n!$; namely, take a class $v_1v_2 \ldots v_n \in \text{Sym}^n(V)$ to $\frac{1}{n!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} v_{\sigma(1)} \otimes \ldots \otimes v_{\sigma(n)}$.
